# Erro de lista está nula mas eu estou preenchendo

Tags: c#

Tenho essa Action em minha controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Details(AzureDiscountGroupModel modelD)
        {
            var discount = _azureDiscountGroupService.GetAll();
            var list = new ResellerListModel();

            var resellers = _resellerService.QueryAll()
                .Include(r => r.WhiteLabels)
                .ToList();

            foreach(var item in resellers)
            {
                list.Id = item.Id;
                list.Name = item.Name;
                list.Alias = item.Alias;
                list.MpnId = item.ResellerMpnId;
                //list.CreatedOn = item.AcceptContractDate;
                //list.WhiteLabel = item.WhiteLabels
            }

            ViewBag.Desconto = discount.Where(x => x.Id > 0);

            ViewBag.DetailReseller = resellers.Where(x => x.AzureDiscountGroupId == modelD.Id);

            return View(modelD);
        }
```

Estou preenchendo essa table assim

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.DetailReseller as IEnumerable<ResellerListModel>)
    {
    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            @item.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Alias
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.WhiteLabel
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.MpnId
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.CreatedOn
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

No momento em que eu tento preencher, recebo esse erro

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referência de objeto não definida para
>   uma instância de um objeto.'

Como faço para iterar por essa model?

**EDIT1**

Fiz essa alteração, para ver se consigo

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Details(AzureDiscountGroupModel modelD)
        {
            var discount = _azureDiscountGroupService.GetAll();
            var list = new List<ResellerListModel>();

            var resellers = _resellerService.QueryAll()
                .Include(r => r.WhiteLabels)
                .ToList();

            foreach(var item in resellers)
            {
                list.Add(CreateListModelFrom(item));
            }

            ViewBag.Desconto = discount.Where(x => x.Id > 0);

            ViewBag.DetailReseller = resellers.Where(x => x.AzureDiscountGroupId == modelD.Id);

            return View(modelD);
        }
```

e essa aqui

```
private ResellerListModel CreateListModelFrom(Reseller reseller)
        {
            var model = new ResellerListModel();

            model.Id = reseller.Id;
            model.Name = reseller.Name;
            model.Alias = reseller.Alias;
            model.MpnId = reseller.ResellerMpnId;

            model.WhiteLabel = true;

            var firstWhiteLabel = reseller.WhiteLabels.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedOn).FirstOrDefault();
            model.CreatedOn = firstWhiteLabel.CreatedOn.ToLocalTime();

            return model;
        }
```

E mesmo assim não consigo iterar pela lista no cshtml

Se faço assim, a lista vem preenchida, mas perco os itens que devem ser mostrados na table

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.DetailReseller as IEnumerable<List<ResellerListModel>>)
```

Mas se faço assim, dá erro de null

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.DetailReseller as List<ResellerListModel>)
```

Comment: Aparentemente está correto. Tente materializar a lista usando um .ToList() quando seta os dados em `ViewBag.DetailReseller = resellers.Where(x => x.AzureDiscountGroupId == modelD.Id);` e verifique se os dados são preenchidos.ao debugar esta linha.

Comment: Colocando um break, vi que a ViewBag está nula devido a isso aqui: `ViewBag.DetailReseller = list.Where(x => x.AzureDiscountGroupId == modelD.Id);`. Não estou populando esse campo na model: `AzureDiscountGroupId`

Comment: Provavelmente ao popular o campo a query vai retornar dados.

Comment: Então, o campo AzureDiscountGroupId está fixo em 2 e não sei porque isso e mesmo setando o model.id == 2, mesmo assim dá erro. A lambda não está funcionando e preciso trazer o ID da tela para o método

Comment: Faltou um ToList() na lambda da ViewBag, mas preciso entender porque está vindo o campo fixo em 2

Answer (score 1):

Fazendo assim resolveu

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Details(AzureDiscountGroupModel modelD)
        {
            var discount = _azureDiscountGroupService.GetAll();
            var list = new List<ResellerListModel>();

            var resellers = _resellerService.QueryAll()
                .Include(r => r.WhiteLabels)
                .ToList();

            foreach(var item in resellers)
            {
                list.Add(CreateListModelFrom(item));
            }

            ViewBag.Desconto = discount.Where(x => x.Id > 0);

            ViewBag.DetailReseller = list.Where(x => x.AzureDiscountGroupId == modelD.Id).ToList();

            return View(modelD);
        }
```

E na View fiz

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.DetailReseller as List<ResellerListModel>)
    {
    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            @(item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @(item.Alias)
        </td>
        <td>
            @(item.WhiteLabel ? "Sim" : "Não")
        </td>
        <td>
            @(item.MpnId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @(item.CreatedOn)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

O método `CreateListModelFrom` tem por finalidade popular a ResellerListModel

Comment: O que você mudou e percebeu?

Comment: @CypherPotato, o `ToList()` na `ViewBag`, a mudança para carregar a `ViewBag`, a criação desse novo método `CreateListModelFrom`, o `List<>`na View e sei lá o que mais, rs. Essas foram as mudanças.

Comment: O que essa `CreateListModelFrom` faz? Seria interessante colocar na resposta, uma vez que pode ajudar outras pessoas com situações semelhantes a sua.

Comment: Ok, mas ela já está no post principal e para não alongar demais a resposta, vou apenas falar sobre o que faz

Comment: Ah sim, não tinha observado. Perdoe.